# Output mysql query to array json

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

How do i go ahead to output mysql row to a var array like this

```
var data = [
  {"name" : "mysql data here "username" ", "hvalue" : mysql data here  "percent"},
];
```

all the possible mysql rows not just 1

I have a mysql query here but for the username there is a column already and the percent should be calculated in the query, could someone help me implement this code into the data array like that

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT username, (SUM(value)/COUNT(value))*100 FROM game".$cg." GROUP BY userid ORDER BY id DESC");
$rows = array();
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: The top snippet looks like javascript. Just to clarify, you need the values in a PHP array correct?

Comment: either just echo json encode it inside `data` or use an xmlhttprequest